# MVC4 validation for select option value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am new in the MVC technology and I have an MVC 4 application and am trying to display a validation for select input(Month and year). I did validation for input type="text" its working fine for me. I need help for select an option. Please help on this?

The View:

```
        <li>
            <div class="requiredField">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountNumber)<span>* </span>
            </div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountNumber, new {@class ="requiredTextBox" })
            <div class="swipeLink">
                @Html.ActionLink("Swipe", "Swipe", "Transaction", new { @class = "swipePopupLink" })
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="requiredField">@Html.Label("Expiration Date")<span>* </span></div>  
            <div class="ExpirationMonthYear">
                @Html.DropDownList("ExpirationMonth", new SelectList(Model.ExpirationMonth, "Value", "Text", 0), new { @class = "requiredTextBox" })
                @Html.DropDownList("ExpirationYear", new SelectList(Model.ExpirationYear, "Value", "Text", 0), new { @class = "requiredTextBox" })
            </div>
        </li>
@Html.ValidationSummary()

           <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js")' type="text/javascript">
           </script>
           <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")' 
           type="text/javascript"></script>
           <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" 
           type="text/javascript"></script>
           <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"  
           type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The Model View:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Account Number")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    [Display(Name = "Expiration Date")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationMonth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationYear { get; set; }
```

advance appreciate for your support

Answer (score 0):

For Drop Down you need bind with one more property to check your validation

```
The ModelView 



 [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Account Number")]
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Expiration Date")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationMonth { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ExpirationYear { get; set; }

        //New property 
        [RegularExpression(@"^[^0]*$", ErrorMessage = "Select Month.")]
        public int ExpMonth{get;set;}

        [RegularExpression(@"^[^0]*$", ErrorMessage = "Select Year.")]
        public int ExpYear {get;set;}
```

The View

```
<li>
        <div class="requiredField">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountNumber)<span>* </span>
        </div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountNumber, new {@class ="requiredTextBox" })
        <div class="swipeLink">
            @Html.ActionLink("Swipe", "Swipe", "Transaction", new { @class = "swipePopupLink" })
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="requiredField">@Html.Label("Expiration Date")<span>* </span></div>  
        <div class="ExpirationMonthYear">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ExpMonth, new SelectList(Model.ExpirationMonth, "Value", "Text", 0), new { @class = "requiredTextBox" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ExpYear, new SelectList(Model.ExpirationYear, "Value", "Text", 0), new { @class = "requiredTextBox" })
        </div>
    </li>
```

NOTE: In above example i have taken **int** data type if it not right then please take it different as per you situation and then apply validation.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I added that code after that I'm getting this error->Already contains a definition for "ExpirationMonth" and Already contains a definition for "ExpirationYear". Can you help on this?         

Please find the path: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lu1j40er8el3jz8/error.png

Comment: Now, that errors are cleared. But not getting fire for validation..
more details about view Model: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lu1j40er8el3jz8/error.png
please give me your support for this.

Comment: I have edit my post you have keep first item in drop down selected by
using "select=true", so instead by using [Required] attribute you must use Regular Expression to check whether selected value in drop down is Zero or Not.i have add expression to check for zero.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7hz6k3phohgbms/error_1.png
Again I have added your exact code. Now I'm getting this error. Could you please try f?

Comment: @ssiva i am apology use DropDownFor instead DropDown as you bind it strongly with ViewModel,i have change it in my post..

Comment: Thanks lot for your help...You saved my time even i have spent much for this...Great appreciate....